# How to compare one field to another using LIKE

Tags: sql, teradata-sql-assistant

I want to so something like the following:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE1
WHERE DATE1 LIKE DATE2 + '%'
```

However, when I try this I get the following error:

"5407: Invalid operation for DateTime or Interval"

I am working in Terdata SQL Assistant

Comment: Why would you use `like` on dates?  Makes no sense at all to me.  That is why sample data and desired results are helpful.

Comment: I can't really get what you are trying to do. How exactly do you want to compare both dates? Examples, please.

Comment: one is in the format "dd/mm/yyy" and the other is in the format "dd/mm/yy hh/mm/ss". I just want to compare the "dd/mm/yyy" bit

Comment: Assuming one is a `date` column and one is a `timestamp`, just cast the timestamp column as a date, and then compare.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use like to compare dates, like is to compare string (varchar), then you can cast this dates to varchar or better way is cast both dates to the same format, for example:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE1
WHERE convert(varchar, DATE1, 103) = convert(varchar, DATE2, 103)
```

This way cast dates to format: DD/MM/YYYY

If you wanna cast to another formats I let you a link that explain more types: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1145/date-and-time-conversions-using-sql-server/

Answer (score 0):

You could potentially just format the dates the same way to compare them.

```
WHERE FORMAT(DATE1, 'dd/mm/yyyy') = FORMAT(DATE2, 'dd/mm/yyyy')
```

Answer (score 0):

date2 is less than 1 day later

```
 where datediff(d,date1,date2) < 1
```

Since your using like ... you could mean within a day before or after.

```
 abs(datediff(d,date1,date2)) < 1
```